# How to update UILabel daily?

Tags: ios, swift

So I want to update the quote only once daily but right now it updates every time I launch it? I appreciate any help!

```
let tasks = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/")!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let data = Json as? [AnyHashable:Any] {

                        if let quote = data["quote"], let cat = data["cat"], let author = data["author"] as? String {

                            print(cat)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.myLabel.text = "\(quote)"
                                    self.authorLabel.text = "\(author)"
                                }

                        }
                    }
                } catch {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    tasks.resume()
```

Comment: There is no way to trigger something like this at particular times, but you might find background fetch useful. It allows data to be loaded when the app is inactive, but the OS controls how frequently this happens, not you. You could check the current date to see if it is a new day before updating, or alternatively use a scheduled push notification if you have a server to do it from. Some info on background fetch: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Answer (score 2):

1- Cache current date's timestamp ( in seconds ) after every retrieve

2- Get current date's timeStamp ( in seconds )

3- Compare if cached not nil

```
if ( current - cached ) > 86400 { // 86400  = 24 * 60 * 60 <<<<< day seconds 
   // update 
}
```